# Dividing variables of type long long to get a percentage?

Tags: objective-c, long-integer

So I am trying to divide two variables that are type `long long`, `totalBytesWritten` and `totalBytesExpected`

Basically I am trying to figure out the percentage complete my file upload is and update the progressbar accordingly.
For example, I am sending 262144 of 1839948 bytes

But when I do `double progress = totalBytesWritten/totalBytesExpected` it gives me some unexpected numbers. When I NSLog progress I get only 0s and then finally 1.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You're performing an integer division, then the result is getting casted to a double but it's too late: you already lost precision.If you just cast one of the two operands to a double, the other one will be also promoted to a double and you'll get a floating point value as result:

```
NSLog(@"%f,"(double)totalBytesWritten/totalBytesExpected);
```

Answer (score 0):

`long long` is a non-decimal data type, so it uses integer division. Thus, since `totalBytesWritten` is probably (hopefully) less than `totalBytesExpected`, you'll always get 0. Try converting them to `double` first, then divide.